# Can a contributor participate in their own research survey?

Tags: authorship, acknowledgement

I was about to give up on my research project for something else. However, a kind friend from my lab was encouraging enough that I was able to redeem the project. And they even went out of their way to participate on survey interviews.

For this "lab friend", would it be inappropriate for me to give them some acknowledgement?

I also looked up the question of "Can an author participate in their own survey?". That much is definitely a possibility in methods such as auto-ethnography. But I don't feel that all disciplines are as keen of the idea. *I also considered giving this friend co-authorship* as a token publication, would that be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

The main question depends on a couple of things. If the scale is large then any individual is unable to skew results. If the participants are anonymous then the author is unable to use any given answer(s) to skew the conclusions. So, in that case, all is well.

And, how much "scale" is enough is a judgement call, of course.

But "encouragement to continue" isn't sufficient for authorship and in many fields would be considered inappropriate. Those that contribute actual intellectual content are authors. An acknowledgement (assuming the first two conditions (scale, anonymity) are met should be fine. But "thanks for the encouragement" is enough.